# How to get an output table on PLY for Python?

Tags: python, parsing, ply

So, in the PLY documentation there's one table that looks something like this:

```
Step Symbol Stack           Input Tokens            Action
---- ---------------------  ---------------------   -------------------------------
1                           3 + 5 * ( 10 - 20 )$    Shift 3
2    3                        + 5 * ( 10 - 20 )$    Reduce factor : NUMBER
3    factor                   + 5 * ( 10 - 20 )$    Reduce term   : factor
4    term                     + 5 * ( 10 - 20 )$    Reduce expr : term
5    expr                     + 5 * ( 10 - 20 )$    Shift +
6    expr +                     5 * ( 10 - 20 )$    Shift 5
7    expr + 5                     * ( 10 - 20 )$    Reduce factor : NUMBER
8    expr + factor                * ( 10 - 20 )$    Reduce term   : factor
9    expr + term                  * ( 10 - 20 )$    Shift *
10   expr + term *                  ( 10 - 20 )$    Shift (
11   expr + term * (                  10 - 20 )$    Shift 10
12   expr + term * ( 10                  - 20 )$    Reduce factor : NUMBER
13   expr + term * ( factor              - 20 )$    Reduce term : factor
14   expr + term * ( term                - 20 )$    Reduce expr : term
15   expr + term * ( expr                - 20 )$    Shift -
16   expr + term * ( expr -                20 )$    Shift 20
17   expr + term * ( expr - 20                )$    Reduce factor : NUMBER
18   expr + term * ( expr - factor            )$    Reduce term : factor
19   expr + term * ( expr - term              )$    Reduce expr : expr - term
20   expr + term * ( expr                     )$    Shift )
21   expr + term * ( expr )                    $    Reduce factor : (expr)
22   expr + term * factor                      $    Reduce term : term * factor
23   expr + term                               $    Reduce expr : expr + term
24   expr                                      $    Reduce expr
25                                             $    Success!
```

But when i run my PLY code it just generates the parser.out file. My call to yacc.yacc looks something like this:

`parser = yacc.yacc(start='program',debug='true')`

Anyways, is there some sort of option on PLY to get a table like the above? Thanks :)

I tried to use the option "write_tables" or "tabmodule" option but it's not working